# Prevent use of my API by authenticated clients (PGP/GPG maybe?)

Tags: android, web-services, public-key-encryption, gnupg, pgp

I have a mobile app (Android) that makes tens of thousands of RESTful webservice requests to my server (per day of course).

For a variety of reasons, specifically the fact that my server has limited resources (both in hardware specs as well as in the form of pricey licensed content which is sent to my app via the API responses), I would like to ensure that only my apps are able to make successful API requests to my webservice.

I do know it's at least theoretically possible to do this, at least for Android-based systems because Google has a method to **[verify backend calls from Android](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2013/01/verifying-back-end-calls-from-android.html)** on a trusted 3rd-party server (e.g., your API server). I believe it's based on OAuth and is tied to the requisite Google account that every Android device must have been setup with.

I actually ended up implementing this, but abandoned it after about a month as it needed the `GoogleAuthUtil` mechanism only provided in the most recent version of Google Play Services which had to be installed on the user's device (and of course this prevented most of my users from upgrading). Another problem is that multiple Google accounts can be on a device, so I'd either have to guess which was the right one, or worse, prompt/annoy the user to choose; these options were absolutely out of the question.

My initial thought on the matter is to use some kind of public key encryption, such as PGP/GPG. Include my API's public key in the app (with the understanding that it's not meant to be secure -- it's a PUBLIC key after all), and then in addition to what I already do to sign my API requests I could encrypt the entire contents using the API's public key.

A few days later (today) I finally got the time to sit down and hash out the design and implementation details, and it quickly dawned on me (as well as Robert below in the comments) that because the API's public key as well as the other signature related logic could theoretically be extracted, a successful hacker could then quite easily generate "genuine" API requests that my API server would decrypt with its private key and be none the wiser.

I did come across these two questions posted on programmers.stackexchange that have some *really* good answers on the subject by people much smarter than me:

- https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/219028/how-to-safeguard-a-rest-api-for-only-trusted-mobile-applications
- https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/220080/is-it-possible-to-check-a-client-side-application-identity-from-server-side

From what I have gathered, I'm willing to say that *yes it's theoretically possible* (just look at Google's `GoogleAuthUtil` OAuth-based backend verification system that I linked to above). However, it's incredibly painful to correctly implement/maintain, so unless your API is serving nuclear launch codes it's probably wise just to obfuscate the requests as best you can to prevent 90% of the cheaters.

If a mod wants to remove this question or mark it as a duplicate please feel free. OTOH, if someone comes along wondering the same thing maybe this will help them -- I never thought to ask this on programmers.stackexchange, but most of my leads were found in those questions. And of course in the unlikely scenario that a security guru sees this and can explain how this can be done relatively easily and effectively well that would be great too. ;)

Comment: What do you do if I decompile your app and extract the public key together with the relevant code for using it? You can never prevent using an API an app-level just making it harder via obfuscation.

Comment: Been giving this a lot of thought, and that just occurred to me (obtaining the API's public key [which I never presumed would be secure -- public keys are meant to be public!] and generating "genuine" API calls), so I came here to see what the community had to offer.

I do have to say I very much disagree with your sentiment that one can never prevent ensuring the authenticity of the API request origin (e.g. the app) on the server side. After all, that's one of the reasons for using SSL: to be (reasonably) assured the computer you are talking to is who they claim to be.

Comment: Since comments have constraints, if you would like to elaborate and explain to a security novice such as myself why indeed you are correct; that it is impossible to prevent an API from being used by only the authorized app. I understand my proposition in the question won't do the trick, but Android has a system that lets you verify your app's API requests on your own trusted server. I actually used it for a few months, but it required the user to sign into their Google account or worse yet I had to guess which account to use. I think I'll research PGP/GPG signatures; hope in that direction?

Comment: Updated question after doing some more research. I think you're right, @Robert, probably best just to obfuscate as best as possible.

Answer (score 1):

Why not generate on client side public/private keys and use the server public key to send the client private one to the server. Store client private key on server side with some kind of request identifier, and further requests could be crypted with client public key, in order to send user credential (is there any on your server?) for example.

Requests could however come from any kind of client aware of your interface, but at least that requests comes from users with valid credentials, otherwise they would fail (still have to got resources to handle wrong request).

Does this makes sens? I'm really new to this subject, but I also have read tons of articles without coming accross to really well defined solution.

Comment: personally in search of practical solutions in Java